# How to make input parameter in powershell function and write it to file?

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

i am trying to learn powershell. And first, that i am doing, i am rewrtiting my code from bash. I had on bash, this function:

```
log=/var/log/test.log

function logging {
echo $(date) "______" "$1" >> $log
}

logging "WWE"
```

In a result i had in my file something like this:

`Mon Jan 21 09:35:55 UTC 2019 ______ WWE`

I want to write the same on powershell. I did:

```
$data = Get-Date 
$log = C:\script_logs\1.txt

function logging ($1) {
Write-Host $data "______" $1 >> $log
}

logging "test, for test"
```

Yes, it writes in console

`1/21/2019 5:48:31 PM ______ test, for test`

But in file it does not write. It writes date only and it opens file. I don't want to open this file during script execution. I just want to write function with parameter. How can i do this ? I just started to learn powershell and i hope, that you will push me in right way.

Answer (score 0):

What about using either

```
start-transcript
stop-transcript
```

which will output everything that would have been written to the console or

```
$log | out-file C:\yourfile.txt
```

at the end?